# IE8 issue with toggle() to show/hide content

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in IE8 only where a link should show/hide content when clicked. IE7 and webkit and gecko browsers work fine, only IE8 is the problem! I can't see what's going wrong with the code I've got, and even just trying show() instead of toggle() doesn't have any effect - am i missing something here? Thanks for any help!

```
    //hide class=hidden elements
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $('a#hide').live("click", function(){
                        $(this).parent().siblings(".hidden:first").toggle();
                        return false;
                    });
```

The above js is for the following html:

```
<a href="#hidden" id="hide">Click to show</a></p>
<p id = "hidden" class = "hidden">
    my content
</p>
```

Comment: Are you using `id="hide"` on more than one element in the page?

Comment: No, just double checked that - only using it once. Bit puzzled by this one, would have expected the same issue to surface in IE7, but it's only IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking your script didn't work not only in IE8, but also in any other browser. Then again, its 1 year later and newer jQuery is out.

But better later then never, here is my answer:

**Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/Vnasb/2/**

In my live demo, I removed unnecessary things and reformatted it a little. I still left the `:first` parameter, since that's a good example. I will also include your own code, that just works. Note that in your code, there is one excess `</p>`

**Script:**

```
$('.hidden').hide();
$('a#hide').live("click", function(){
    $('.hidden').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

**Body:**

```
<a href="#hidden" id="hide">Click to show</a></p>
<p id = "hidden" class = "hidden">
    my content
</p>
```

I'm not sure, how you guys did things back in the "old days", but the `[...].parent().siblings(".hidden:first")[...]` was the problematic part.

**Side note:** Was the script meant to automatically scroll to the viewpoint of `#hidden`, when clicked on the trigger-element? With `<a href="#hidden" ...`? That cant work, as you are returning `false` in the jQuery function.

**PS:** Tested on **IE9**, **IE8**, **IE7** and of course on **FF** -- works perfectly.